# kivy/buildozer App shows 4. navigation key on android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

When I start any kivy application on my android mobile phone, it shows a 4. navigation button. It seems the button doesn't have any functionality.

What is the purpose of this button and is it possible to disable it?

[image]

Basic example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MainWindow(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SettingsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

SettingsApp().run()
```

Comment: Paste code, please.

Comment: What API number are you targeting? This appears by default with very old ones.

Comment: @inclement Target is buildozer default (19, minimum 9)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr: It happens with every application. Added absolute Basic application.

Comment: Try setting the minimum api higher, maybe to 12.

Comment: It works but it needs at least api version 14. Edited the title